# pkg-config: best practice for setting -rpath?

Tags: c++, c, pkg-config, rpath, library-path

Are there any best practices to set `-rpath` or libtool's `-R` based on a `pkg-config` output?  Do I have to resort to a `sed` trick?

Answer (score -2):

Generally rpath is not portable, that's why pkg-config packages does not have it, because all the libraries are in the default system path. So why would you use rpath in this case?

Comment: "because all the libraries are in the default system path" No, pkg-config (together with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`) is much more versatile.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but can you give an example that a pkg-config library have rpath in other directories?